# How forecast weekly sales?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, seasonality, tbats

I'm working on a forecasting weekly sales by category. I want to make sure I'm doing it correctly.

```
    date    DiningSales
3/1/2015    243334
3/8/2015    556637
3/15/2015   554315
......
10/1/2017   343660
```

I've read Rob Hyndman website and see he recommends TBATS for weekly data. My date range is from 3/1/2015-10/1/2017. I want to predict the next 4 weeks. Here is my code:

```
dining.data <- read.csv("sales_dining.csv", fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")
dining.df <- dining.data$DiningSales

dining.ts <- ts(dining.df, 
                 freq=365.25/7, start=2015+59/365.25)

dining.tbats <- tbats(dining.ts)
dining.fc <- forecast(dining.tbats, h=4)
plot(dining.fc, ylab="dining orders")
```

The code runs but my predictions for the next 4 weeks seem way off. My questions are:

1. Did I use the correct frequency to get weekly data?
2. Is my start date correct? I want the start date to be 3/1/2015.
3. The next four predictions change the date to 10/7 to 2017.768. Is there a way to have the date in the results be in an actual date format?
4. Finally it seems like there isn't a lot out there for weekly forecast, rather monthly, annual or even daily or hourly. Is weekly data harder to have a more accurate prediction?

Comment: in terms of why one should use daily data take a look at this http://www.autobox.com/cms/index.php/blog/entry/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-monthly-weekly-and-daily-data

Comment: can you 1) show the historical data 2) show the results  3) show the forecasts u are unhappy with

Answer (score 4):

`freq=365.25/7` means you are assuming a year-long seasonality in your data. Since your results don't look good, try removing the seasonality by setting `freq=1`.

You can also try using the `ets` and `auto.arima` functions with `freq=1` to see what kind of results they give. If the seasonality of your data is not strong, using a non-seasonal model will likely give better results.

You don't have a ton of data, but you could perhaps hold out a test set of 1 year to compare the `tbats`, `ets`, and `auto.arima` predictions.

If you have an external data that might affect sales (e.g. holidays or promotions) you can include that data in the `auto.arima` model, but not `tbats` or `ets`.

Also, `243334` on 3/1/2015 vs `556637` on 3/8/2015 is a pretty huge jump for 1 week: are you sure you don't have a data quality issue?